# how to update bar chart with new values in mpAndroid Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

This is my code:-

Here generating bar chart with mpandroidchart libs in my app and want to update these below values with new values can you people provide me a solution thank you

```
BarChart chart = (BarChart)findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(90, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(20, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(56, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(82, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(34, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(86, 5));
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("ENG");
    labels.add("SOC");
    labels.add("SIC");
    labels.add("MAT");
    labels.add("HIN");
    labels.add("TEL");
    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
    dataset.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
    data.setGroupSpace(20);
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.setDescription("");
    chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.setGridBackgroundColor(128);
    chart.setBorderColor(255);
    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
    chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.setDrawBorders(false);
```

how to update above chart with new custom values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your owe arrays of values and labels to set custom values;

```
int[] values={12,36,78,5,8};
String[] labels={"yorLbl1","yorLbl2","yorLbl3","yorLbl4","yorLbl5"};

    BarChart chart = (BarChart)findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++){
   entries.add(new BarEntry(values[i], i));
    labels.add(labels[i]);
   }
```